# NullPointerException exception when using intersect command

Tags: java, javafx

For a project at school we need to program a game in **JavaFx**, we're almost ready with the game but I get a strange error when I use the intersects command (see attachment 1) [error section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmUdH.png).
In the second and third attachment are the constructors which I use in those line where the error is [constructor_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhyDx.png) [constructor_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyHY7.png).
and the last attachment is the ouput window with the error lines [output_window_with_error_lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZBgw.png).

I already have read the section on this site over `NullPointerException` but I cant find the fault.

Main code:

```
if (kogelView.getBoundsInParent().intersects(enemyView1.getBoundsInParent()))
            {

                  enemyDoodModel1.setXDodeEnemy(enemyModel1.getX());
                  enemyDoodView1.UpdateEnemyDood(enemyDoodModel1);

                  enemyDoodModel2.setXDodeEnemy(enemyModel2.getX());
                  enemyDoodView2.UpdateEnemyDood(enemyDoodModel2);

            }
}
```

constructor_1:

```
public void setXDodeEnemy(int xPos)
    {
        this.xDood = xPos;

    }
```

constructor_2:

```
public int getX()
    {
        return this.xEnemy;

    }
```

Comment: Please share you error and code in the question.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] inside the question itself (not as pictures).

Comment: You use the term *"constructor"* wrong. The methods you posted below the "heading" `constructor_1` and `constructor_2` are a setter and a getter method. None of them is actually a constructor...